# UrlFetchApp.fetch : Address unavailable

Tags: google-apps-script

in google apps scripts, I use `UrlFetchApp.fetch` for get a url

```
var url = "http://my_url/for_vars?var=355&test=1";
```

when I use directly my script, every work ok, but when I use time-driven trigger I get a mail with this errors

```
Address unavailable: http://my_url/for_vars?var=355&amp;test=1 (line 5, file &quot;Code&quot;)
```

why don't work with time-driven trigger ?

Comment: I have a call to UrlFetchApp.fetch on a time-driven trigger and works without problem. Can you provide more information to see if I can help?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues here.

a. There seem to be two ampersands in the problem URL - one before var and the other after 355. See how this came about.

b. The URL is encoded. I don't think the ampersands need to be encoded here.

Comment: with respect to a), sorry, not is `&amp;var=355&amp;test=1` is `var=355&amp;test=1`. I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. UrlFetch runs successfuly when I run manually, but when I use triggers, it give me "address unavailable" error!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open ticket](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2758) regarding this problem.